# higan not working properly

Tags: technical-issues, emulation, snes

So i have downloaded higan v094 - 32bit, and I cant import any games to it (except ALTTP). Every time I navigate to game folder to import games it doesn't show any game files like .sfc .gba and so on. The only game it shows is alttp.sfc,  yet when i load it - higan crashes. Any ways to make higan detect files and don`t crash on start?